# create DataColumnCollection from data condition

Tags: c#, datatable

I have this DataTable

```
+----+---+---+---+
| id | s | m | l |
+----+---+---+---+
| 1  | 2 | 3 |   |
+----+---+---+---+
| 2  |   | 3 | 4 |
+----+---+---+---+
```

`s, m, l` represent t-shirt sizes, and the values are the quantities. I have to show for a single row (let's say `id = 1`) only the size columns that have values. So, for my row I will show only columns s and m. Is there a way to take off a data table only the columns I need?

Comment: Not clear. A `DataTable` contains typically multiple `DataRows` but only a single `DataColumnCollection`. So you could remove all columns where there is not at least one row with a value, if that's what you want. Otherwise you would remove colums where there is no value in row1 but on row2.

Comment: Just a collection of columns would be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `DataTable` contains typically multiple `DataRows` but only a single `DataColumnCollection`. So you could remove all columns where there is not at least one row with a value.

Then you need to create a new `DataTable` with only the "filled" columns. Following approach works not only with a single `DataRow` but also with multiple:

```
var rows = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(row => row.Field<int>("ID") == id);    // a LINQ query

var columnsWithoutValues =  dataTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Where(col => rows.All(r => r.IsNull(col)));  // columns without values

DataTable tblResult = dataTable.Clone(); // same columns no data
foreach (DataColumn colToRemove in columnsWithoutValues)
    tblResult.Columns.Remove(colToRemove.ColumnName); // remove columns without data

tblResult.BeginLoadData();   // disable constraints temporarily
foreach (DataRow row in rows)
{
    DataRow newRow = tblResult.Rows.Add();
    foreach (DataColumn col in tblResult.Columns)
        newRow[col] = row[col.ColumnName];
}
tblResult.EndLoadData();
```

Comment: I get that id column cannot accept null as a value, at the line `DataRow newRow = tblResult.Rows.Add();` Maybe should it be `DataRow newRow = tblResult.NewRow();`

Comment: I added the above line and added the row to the table after the foreach, and it worked! Thanks! Posting the right code

Comment: @Phate01: you should use the code i've added now. Disable all constraints during data-loading with `BeginLoadData ... EndLoadData`. That's more efficient.